# Sqlite - Update row with a new ID

Tags: sqlite

I have to update a row and update row ID to new ID .

Like below :

```
ID(auto inc)      name
1                 Bob
2                 John
```

And after updating row 1 ( Bob ) table must be like :

```
ID(auto inc)      name
2                 John
3                 Bob
```

is there any way to do this without delete and insert ?

Comment: Have you tried to use `UPDATE`?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by changing a row's primary key? There's few good reasons to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For create table I use:
   CREATE TABLE student (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT);

Insert some date to table :
   INSERT INTO student (name) VALUES ('Bob'); 
   INSERT INTO student (name) VALUES ('Pol');

For update use:
   UPDATE student SET id=5 WHERE id=1;